# Reffering to new tab and saving file with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE to post a form.
After posting, the site opens a new tab (target="_blank") with a .XML file, which I want to save locally.

How do I refer to this tab and command Selenium to save it in a specific local folder?

Additional information:

- After hitting the Submit button, Selenium log states: "[warn] Opening window '_blank', which is not a real window name. Randomizing target to be: selenium_blank17837" (As you may have guessed, the number is different every time I run the code).
- The XML tab doesn't have a title, but I could differentiate it from my previous tab using parts of the URL (I don't know if that helps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
  Set<String> winSet;
  winSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
  while (winSet.size() < 2) {
    Thread.sleep(250);
      winSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
  }
  String windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

  driver.switchTo().window(winSet.toArray()[1].toString());
  while (driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("about:blank")){
    Thread.sleep(250);
  };
  URL Address = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    File fName = new File("filename.xml");
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(Address, fName);
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
```